# How to print the word with the most consecutive vowels?

Tags: java

Not sure where I'm going wrong in my programming. The goal is to load a file and find the word with the most consecutive vowels. This code is not giving me the correct word. It gives me "aalii" when it should give me "cooeeing" Can anyone please help me?

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class manyVowels {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner fileIn = null;
        try {
            //locate and open file
            fileIn = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("words.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            //if the file cannot be found, the program prints the message and quits
            System.out.println("File not found. ");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        String word;
        if (fileIn.hasNext()) //if there is another word do as shown below
        {
        //seek consecutive vowels
        word = fileIn.next();
            for(int i=0;i <word.length();i++){
                if((word.charAt(i) == 'A') || 
                    (word.charAt(i) == 'E') ||
                    (word.charAt(i) == 'I') || 
                    (word.charAt(i) == 'O') ||
                    (word.charAt(i) == 'U') ||
                (word.charAt(i) == 'a') || 
                    (word.charAt(i) == 'e') ||
                    (word.charAt(i) == 'i') || 
                    (word.charAt(i) == 'o') ||
                    (word.charAt(i) == 'u')) {
            //prints the final word with the most consecutive vowels
            System.out.println("The word with the most consecutive vowels is: " + word);
            System.exit(0);
        }

        fileIn.close();
    }
}}}
```

---

UPDATE: I got this far, but now it is saying that line 34 has an "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException"

```js
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class manyVowels {

  public static final String wordList = "words.txt";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner fileIn = null;
        try {
            //locate and open file
            fileIn = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("words.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            //if the file cannot be found, the program prints the message and quits
            System.out.println("File not found. ");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        String word = null;
        if (fileIn.hasNext()) //if there is another word continue
        {

            String finalWord = null; // defines the word with most consecutive vowels
            int maxVowels = 0;//sets initial value to 0
            while (fileIn.hasNext()) {
                // for each word in the file
                int vowels = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < word.length() && i < word.length() - maxVowels + vowels; i++) {
                    // for each character in the word, and exit early if the word is not long enough to beat maxVowels
                    if (hasVowels(word.charAt(i))) {
                        // consonants reset this to 0
                        vowels++;
                    } else {
                        // reached the end of the word so check if the count is higher than maxVowels
                        if (vowels > maxVowels) {
                            maxVowels = vowels;
                            finalWord = word;
                        }
                        vowels = 0;
                    }
                }
                // comparing vowels to maxVowels
                if (vowels > maxVowels) {
                    maxVowels = vowels;
                    finalWord = word;
                }
            }

            //seek vowels
            word = fileIn.next();
            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                if
                        ((word.charAt(i) == 'A')
                        || (word.charAt(i) == 'E')
                        || (word.charAt(i) == 'I')
                        || (word.charAt(i) == 'O')
                        || (word.charAt(i) == 'U')
                        || (word.charAt(i) == 'a')
                        || (word.charAt(i) == 'e')
                        || (word.charAt(i) == 'i')
                        || (word.charAt(i) == 'o')
                        || (word.charAt(i) == 'u')) {
                    //prints the final word with the most consecutive vowels
                    System.out.println("The word with the most consecutive vowels is: " + word);
                    System.exit(0);
                }

            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean hasVowels(char charAt) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Inserted by template."); //NetBeans generated method
    }
}
```

Comment: you're not sorting anything, just printing words as they come...

Comment: `it should give me "cooeeing"` why it should give you this?

Comment: oh @Sebas. It should give me cooeeing because the word on the file (which is a long list of words, has this word in it which is the one with most vowels.

Comment: @stephaniegross2 what is your file content?

Comment: The code as written will read the first word in the file. If that word has ANY vowels it will print the message. Then the program exits without reading any more words.  A program that reads a file one line at a time must contain a loop of some kind.  Your program contains no loops.  If you don't understand this it's time to go talk to your professor or teaching assistant.  If we just do your homework for you you will not learn anything.

Comment: http://www49.zippyshare.com/v/69463124/file.html this is the file link...thanks @JimGarrison that gives me some insight :)

Comment: @stephaniegross2 I found the list automation = 6
automatize = 6
adequacies = 6
louisianan = 6
obituaries = 6
incautious = 6
equipoises = 6
inadequate = 6
obsequious = 6
auditioned = 6
evaluation = 6
the totall is the number of the word is 100

Comment: @stephaniegross2 if you have not found the answer, lemme know so I can post up mine

Answer (score 1):

Try writing out your program in plain language, you're not actually checking how many consecutive vowels there are.

```
Open file
If the file contains a word, continue
For each letter in the first word do:
    if the letter is a vowel,
        print "The word with the most consecutive vowels is: " + word
        exit the program
```

So you are actually not doing any checking of how many consecutive vowels there are, but rather checking if there is a vowel in the first word.

Try writing up some pseudocode of what you want to do broken up like I did before you try to write the program

Comment: the op wants the most consecutive vowels not just find a one

Comment: yea, I might have been a little unclear, but I guess he knows best what he wants. The point is that what he's really checking is if the first word contains a vowel

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

if (fileIn.hasNext()) 
use
while(fileIn.hasNext())